# `conda activate <env>` messes up prompt

Tags: conda, command-prompt

Recently my prompt gets messed up when activating a conda environment.

It basically removes everything except the environment name.
After deactivating the environment again there is no prompt left, i.e. `$PS1` is empty.

I expect something like

```
[<standard prompt>] $

[<standard prompt>] $ conda activate <env>

(<env>) [<standard prompt>] $ conda deactivate

[<standard prompt>] $
```

However recently this changed to the following

```bash
[<standard prompt>] $

[<standard prompt>] $ conda activate <env>

(<env>) conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is due to the recent conda version `22.9.0` (see also https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885).

As mentioned in the bug report, this is solved by running

```bash
conda init bash
```

This will modify (next to other files) the following

```
<conda base>/condabin/conda
<conda base>/bin/conda
<conda base>/bin/conda-env
```